# Do new USB flash drives use advanced format (AF)?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, sectors, advanced-format

I just want to know if that new feature (*AF - advanced format*) on some hard   drives, is present on flash (USB external disk) drives as well. I'm a little bit confused because a simple check on `/dev/sd*` with `fdisk -l` clearly
shows that it hasn't.

By other side a *USB* stick is derived from a *EEPROM* now called "flash" type, so there are no sector or any other physical component in the same way that we can see it on a traditional *HDD*.

Comment: USB flash drives are NANDs like SSD, not EEPROM. Generally NAND flash chips have very big sector size (on the order of MBs) and just expose the logical sector out, since having 1MB cluster is unrealistic